# gcc assembly when passing by reference and by value

Tags: c++, loops, gcc, assembly

I have a simple function that computes a product of
two double arrays:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>

struct S {
    double *x;
    double *y;
    double *z;
};

void f(S& s, size_t n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 2) {
        __m128d xs = _mm_load_pd(&s.x[i]);
        __m128d ys = _mm_load_pd(&s.y[i]);
        _mm_store_pd(&s.z[i], _mm_mul_pd(xs, ys) );
    }
    return;
}

int main(void) {
    S s;
    size_t size = 4;
    posix_memalign((void **)&s.x, 16, sizeof(double) * size);
    posix_memalign((void **)&s.y, 16, sizeof(double) * size);
    posix_memalign((void **)&s.z, 16, sizeof(double) * size);
    f(s, size);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the first argument of function f is passed in by reference.
Let's look at the resulting assembly of f() (I removed some irrelevant
pieces, inserted comments and put some labels):

```
$ g++ -O3 -S asmtest.cpp 


        .globl      _Z1fR1Sm
_Z1fR1Sm:
        xorl        %eax, %eax
        testq       %rsi, %rsi
        je  .L1
.L5:
        movq        (%rdi), %r8             # array x   (1)
        movq        8(%rdi), %rcx           # array y   (2)
        movq        16(%rdi), %rdx          # array z   (3)
        movapd      (%r8,%rax,8), %xmm0     # load x[0]
        mulpd       (%rcx,%rax,8), %xmm0    # multiply x[0]*y[0]
        movaps      %xmm0, (%rdx,%rax,8)    # store to y
        addq        $2, %rax                # and loop
        cmpq        %rax, %rsi
        ja  .L5
```

Notice that addresses of arrays x, y, z are loaded into general-purpose
registers on each iteration, see statements (1),(2),(3).  Why doesn't gcc move
these instructions outside the loop?

Now make a local copy (not a deep copy) of the structure:

```
void __attribute__((noinline)) f(S& args, size_t n) {
    S s = args;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 2) {
        __m128d xs = _mm_load_pd(&s.x[i]);
        __m128d ys = _mm_load_pd(&s.y[i]);
        _mm_store_pd(&s.z[i], _mm_mul_pd(xs, ys) );
    }
    return;
}
```

Assembly:

```
_Z1fR1Sm:
.LFB525:
        .cfi_startproc
        xorl        %eax, %eax
        testq       %rsi, %rsi
        movq        (%rdi), %r8     # (1)
        movq        8(%rdi), %rcx   # (2)
        movq        16(%rdi), %rdx  # (3)
        je  .L1
.L5:
        movapd      (%r8,%rax,8), %xmm0
        mulpd       (%rcx,%rax,8), %xmm0
        movaps      %xmm0, (%rdx,%rax,8)
        addq        $2, %rax
        cmpq        %rax, %rsi
        ja  .L5
.L1:
        rep ret
```

Notice that unlike in the previous code,
loads (1), (2), (3) are now outside the loop.

I would appreciate an explanation why these two assembly
codes are different. Is memory aliasing relevant here?
Thanks.

$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 5.2.1-21) 5.2.1 20151003

Comment: and your gcc version is...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath apparently anything from 4.4.7 to 5.2.0 at least. Also `icc` does the same, but `clang` doesn't.

Comment: $ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 5.2.1-21) 5.2.1 20151003. I appended to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, gcc is reloading `s.x` and `s.y` with each iteration of the loop because gcc does not know if `&s.z[i]` for some `i` aliases part of the `S` object passed by reference to `f(S&, size_t)`.

With gcc 5.2.0, applying `__restrict__` to `S::z` and the `s` reference parameter to `f()`, i.e.:

```
struct S {
    double *x;
    double *y;
    double *__restrict__ z;
};

void f(S&__restrict__ s, size_t n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 2) {
        __m128d xs = _mm_load_pd(&s.x[i]);
        __m128d ys = _mm_load_pd(&s.y[i]);
        _mm_store_pd(&s.z[i], _mm_mul_pd(xs, ys));
    }
    return;
}
```

.. causes gcc to generate:

```
__Z1fR1Sm:
LFB518:
    testq   %rsi, %rsi
    je  L1
    movq    (%rdi), %r8
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movq    8(%rdi), %rcx
    movq    16(%rdi), %rdx
    .align 4,0x90
L4:
    movapd  (%r8,%rax,8), %xmm0
    mulpd   (%rcx,%rax,8), %xmm0
    movaps  %xmm0, (%rdx,%rax,8)
    addq    $2, %rax
    cmpq    %rax, %rsi
    ja  L4
L1:
    ret
```

With Apple Clang 700.1.76, only `__restrict__` on the `s` reference is needed:

```
__Z1fR1Sm:                              ## @_Z1fR1Sm
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    testq   %rsi, %rsi
    je  LBB0_3
## BB#1:                                ## %.lr.ph
    movq    (%rdi), %rax
    movq    8(%rdi), %rcx
    movq    16(%rdi), %rdx
    xorl    %edi, %edi
    .align  4, 0x90
LBB0_2:                                 ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movapd  (%rax,%rdi,8), %xmm0
    mulpd   (%rcx,%rdi,8), %xmm0
    movapd  %xmm0, (%rdx,%rdi,8)
    addq    $2, %rdi
    cmpq    %rsi, %rdi
    jb  LBB0_2
LBB0_3:                                 ## %._crit_edge
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
```

Comment: Strangely, `-fstrict-aliasing` doesn't help. I probably misunderstand what the option does.

Comment: I am quite certain you are right, the confusing part is that the three extra loads are loading addresses from %rdi and not the actual array data.

Comment: @DanielTrebbien Thanks, I understand that part (I wrote this in comments to the assembly in the original post).  The problem is to understand why aliasing is involved; when we write s.z[i]=s.x[i]*s.y[i], s.z could be aliased with s.x or s.y, and additional load will be needed if we reuse s.z[i] later in the code, but like you said it is reloading *addresses*. The input pointer (pointer to struct) is not aliased to anything, i.e. we do not have f(S&s1, S&s2) and should not have to reload the contents that s1, s2 are pointing to. I probably need to think a bit more about this.

Comment: @Jester -fstrict-aliasing I believe tells gcc that if pointers of different types are dereferenced, they will not refer to the same memory.